# Int overflow when creating php datetime

Tags: php, datetime

I am currently working on displaying a moment. I want the view to use `DateTime->format(..)`. The value I am getting from the API is `1502462223168`. However, this is displayed as `1945-5-26 16:36` instead of `2017-8-11 16:37`, since the original value exceeds the PHP_MAX_INT value on the system.

Is there a way I can use the original value, maybe as a String, to create the DateTime object?

Comment: JavaScript handles time in milliseconds, PHP does not. Although there is `microtime()`, PHP doesn't deal with milliseconds in DateTime objects, `strtotime()` and so on.

Comment: That ended up being the case, Java (not script) and PHP handling timestamps differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your timestamp value is in milliseconds, divide it by `1000` and then use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), like:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$stamp = intval(1502462223168/1000);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", $stamp)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $date;
```

Comment: Great, I ended up dividing the timestamp by 1000 in the back end and the PHP worked perfectly

Comment: yea that would remove the need to division by 1000 when displaying the formatted date. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will be working fine for your question

```
$timestamp = 1465298940;
$datetimeFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

$date = new DateTime();
// If you must have use time zones
// $date = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Helsinki'));
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
echo $date->format($datetimeFormat);
```